# Spark 2.0: Exception on self joining temporary tables

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, self-join, apache-spark-2.0

I have faced an interesting problem while using Spark 2.0. Here is my situation:

1. create a temporary view V1 using sql
2. create a temporary view V2 using self join of V1

```
select
    a.*,
    b.bcol3
from
(
    select
        col1,
        col2,
        sum(col3) over(partition by
                        col1,
                        col2                        
                        order by col3desc rows unbounded preceding
        )as col3
    from V1
)a
join
(
    select
        col1,
        col2,
        sum(col3) over(partition by
                        market,
                        timegrouptype,
                        periodunit,
                        period
                        order by trxquantity desc  rows unbounded preceding
        )as bcol3
    from V1
)b
on a.col1=b.col1 and a.col2=b.col2
```

When I get result from V2 (using count, select *), I get exceptions like this:

```
    org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$TreeNodeException: execute, tree:
Exchange SinglePartition
+- *HashAggregate(keys=[], functions=[partial_count(1)], output=[count#73739L])
   +- *Project
      +- *SortMergeJoin [market#69662, timegrouptype#67731, periodunit#67733, period#67732, hcp_system_id#69357], [market#73717, timegrouptype#73491, periodunit#73493, period#73492, hcp_system_id#73608], Inner
         :- *Sort [market#69662 ASC, timegrouptype#67731 ASC, periodunit#67733 ASC, period#67732 ASC, hcp_system_id#69357 ASC], false, 0
         :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(market#69662, timegrouptype#67731, periodunit#67733, period#67732, hcp_system_id#69357, 200)
         :     +- *HashAggregate(keys=[hcp_system_id#69357, market#69662, timegrouptype#67731, periodunit#67733, period#67732, displayname#67734], functions=[], output=[hcp_system_id#69357, market#69662, timegrouptype#67731, periodunit#67733, period#67732])
         :        +- Exchange hashpartitioning(hcp_system_id#69357, market#69662, timegrouptype#67731, periodunit#67733, period#67732, displayname#67734, 200)
         :           +- *HashAggregate(keys=[hcp_system_id#69357, market#69662, timegrouptype#67731, periodunit#67733, period#67732, displayname#67734], functions=[], output=[hcp_system_id#69357, market#69662, timegrouptype#67731, periodunit#67733, period#67732, displayname#67734])
         :              +- *Project [timegrouptype#67731, periodunit#67733, period#67732, displayname#67734, hcp_system_id#69357, market#69662]
         :                 +- *SortMergeJoin [product_system_id#69514], [product#69666], Inner
         :                    :- *Sort [product_system_id#69514 ASC], false, 0
         :                    :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(product_system_id#69514, 200)
         :                    :     +- *Project [timegrouptype#67731, periodunit#67733, period#67732, displayname#67734, hcp_system_id#69357, product_system_id#69514]
         :                    :        +- *SortMergeJoin [productgroup_system_id#69829], [productgroup_system_id#69636], Inner
         :                    :           :- *Sort [productgroup_system_id#69829 ASC], false, 0
         :                    :           :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(productgroup_system_id#69829, 200)
         :                    :           :     +- *Project [timegrouptype#67731, periodunit#67733, period#67732, displayname#67734, hcp_system_id#69357, product_system_id#69514, productgroup_system_id#69829]
         :                    :           :        +- *SortMergeJoin [product_system_id#69514], [product_system_id#69827], Inner
         :                    :           :           :- *Sort [product_system_id#69514 ASC], false, 0
         :                    :           :           :  +- *Project [timegrouptype#67731, periodunit#67733, period#67732, displayname#67734, hcp_system_id#69357, product_system_id#69514]
         :                    :           :           :     +- *SortMergeJoin [product_system_id#69242], [product_system_id#69514], Inner
         :                    :           :           :        :- *Sort [product_system_id#69242 ASC], false, 0
         :                    :           :           :        :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(product_system_id#69242, 200)
```

......There are more.

There were no error for such queries in Spark 1.6.2. Thie exception happens only with later version of Spark 2.0.

Has anyone faced this issue? Do you know why it is throwing exceptions?

NOTE: The solution to avoid the exception is to cache V1. Or whatever tables you are using for self join.

Comment: Is the NOTE the answer? Please consider moving (a clearer version of?) it to an answer post, which (after a time) you can accept. This shows others your question was resolved.

Comment: That's a solution to avoid the exception. But that does not say why we are having this exceptions on Spark 2.0 in the first place.

Comment: This code doesn't parse (order by col3desc), please give actual code & error. Please read and act on [mcve].

Comment: This would seem to be a bug. The error certainly isn't proper behaviour for the query. Presumably an infinite loop. What is the other end of the trace?